# Can I use Google+ for image hosting on forum sites?

Tags: google-plus, images

Often, I need to host an image that I want to post in a forum or phpBB site that doesn't accept attachments. I used to use ImageShack until they started charging for their service.

I have a Gmail account, so is Google+ a viable way to host images?

Comment: use imgur? google+ should work, though you might have to set the privacy settings to public. It's actually a good idea I think, since google+ gives you unlimited storage space for photos below a certain resolution.

Comment: I just don't want a bunch of social-media mumbo-jumbo to go along with it.  Flikr works fine if you don't mind the mumbo-jumbo, but I was considering google+ since I already have it and don't use it for anything.  Imgur has all kinds of images that I don't want to be associated with.  The trick would be getting that bb-link...

Comment: It is possible to do this with Flickr, but it's against their rules unless you include the link back to the Flickr photo page. I'd like to  know if the same is true for the new Google Photos... maybe I'll post a new question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hotlinking images is not officially supported by Google+. However I'm not currently aware of any restrictions to doing it. You can go through the [Picasa Web interface](https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/myphotos?noredirect=1) which does officially support hotlinking images. Some people suspect that Picasa Web will be retired soon though so that might not work very long.

Comment: Abraham, I think you are right.  It seems that you *can* use Google+ for image hosting, but it isn't particularly designed for it, and you have to do some tricks, such as relingquishing permissions.  My beef with this is that it opens your profile up and you will probably get lots of g-spam as a result.

Answer (score 3):

Google allows public anonymous access to images if you use absolute address of the image. One simple way to find absolute path of an image (in Google Chrome) is to right click on the image and choose "Open Image in New Tab", then you can see the absolute path of the image in the address bar of newly opened tab. You can use this address in **img** tags. But remember, to be able to open an image in a new tab (I'm absolutely talking about this simple method) you should not use the "Zoom" feature of Google+ photos, otherwise you have to find the absolute path of image another way (by inspecting the element containing the image in the developer panel and finding the path)

Answer (score 2):

I could not make it work. The best I could do is make a shared album with setting Sharing Options/Share Album ON, and I inserted the Share Link in my post. Not 100% but better than nothing.